# Jsoup Element.hasText returns true for &nbsp;

Tags: java, jsoup

The documentation for jsoup's Element.hasText method says :

> Test if this element has any text content (that is not just whitespace).

But the following example says otherwise:

```
    String html1 = "<html><!-- no text here --></html>";
    String html2 = "<html><!-- this is text -->&nbsp;</html>";

    System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(html1).hasText());
    System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(html2).hasText());
```

The output is

```
false
true
```

I was hoping for

```
false 
false
```

Is there anyway to get Jsoup to consider `&nbsp;` as whitespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you can't. Jsoup uses `Character.isWhitespace()` to determine if a text contains something except whitespaces. This behaviour can not be changed (configured). And `Character.isWhitespace()` Javadoc says:

> A character is a Java whitespace character if and only if it satisfies one of the following criteria:
>
> - It is a Unicode space character (SPACE_SEPARATOR, LINE_SEPARATOR, or PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR) but **is not** also a non-breaking space ('**\u00A0**', '\u2007', '\u202F').

So you are on your own.

You can do smth. like

```
org.jsoup.helper.StringUtil.isBlank(element.ownText().replaceAll("\u00A0", ""));
```

`StringUtil.isBlank(String)` is used in `Element.hasText()`, so you will have the same behaviour, but all non-breakable space characters will be removed.